# Checking value of a null field

Tags: mysql, boolean

Why does this return 0 records?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        null as 'first'
) a
WHERE
    first <> 'TEST'
```

`Null` is not a word 'TEST'. I understand we could use `Is Not Null` but this came up because if I have a field that has

- Null records that may not need to be excluded
- Records with valid data that I want to exclude
- Records with valid data I do not want to exclude

I'd rather just say "give me everything that isn't "TEST".

Comment: From the childhood we learn that when column is nullable, you need to use 2 conditions - ` `first is not NULL and first <> 'TEST'`. Nulls are just ignored

Comment: @T.S. sounds like you had a really good childhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null is neither equal nor not equal to any other value, including null itself.  Comparison operators return null when either operand is null:

`select null <> 'TEST'` returns null.

So does `select null <> null`.

You can use null-safe equals `<=>`, negated, instead:

`where not(first <=> 'TEST')`

or use coalesce:

`where coalesce(first, '') <> 'TEST'`